# PHP Centering strings with printf()

Tags: php, printf

## Q: How to center a string using `printf` ??

I know how to align left and right using `printf` func, as follows,

```php
$str = '-DaTa-';
printf(''%-50s'', $str); #leftAlign / PadRight
printf(''%50s'', $str);  #RightAlign/ PadLeft
```

> Output,
>
> ```
> '-DaTa-                                            '
> '                                            -DaTa-'
> ```

But, How am i gonna center the String like this,

```
'                      -DaTa-                      '
```

After Searching for this I found a few answers but non of them were written in `PHP`. So, I am having difficulty trying to understand them. So, I asked this question again focusing on `PHP`.

> EDIT:  I just wanted a answer that uses only `printf` func. because using `str_pad` is ok, But in case of a lot of data for centering in this form becomes ugly. AND, I already knew it was possible to achive using `str_pad`, thats why I taged the question with `printf`....

Comment: @DipakDholakiya  that answer is in c language

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: https://3v4l.org/sY9IP